# javascript form matching fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm not a JavaScript coder, but copied some js from this link and tried to use in my form, without success. Could be the basic setup, such as `onclick` that's not right. Just guessing since I had to add that in myself. I am also using Tectite's formmail, which is validating the form. That site is Tectite.com. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
// Checking to make sure email field is on the form
function validatecompare() {
    if (typeof f.email2 != "undefined") {
        if ((f.email2.value != f.email1.value) && (f.sameAsShip.checked)) {
            customAlert("email2", bnadd_msg_005);
            if ((typeof TeaLeaf != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client.tlAddEvent != "undefined")) {
                var nVO = {
                    ErrorMessage: bnadd_msg_018
                }
                TeaLeaf.Event.tlAddCustomEvent(subtype, nVO);
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Validate that email address has @ and .
        if (f.email2 && (f.email2.value != f.email1.value) && (!editEmail(f.email2.value, 'Email Address'))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (addrType == atBill) {

            if (f.email2.value != f.email1.value) {
                customAlert("email2", bnadd_msg_005);
                if ((typeof TeaLeaf != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client.tlAddEvent != "undefined")) {
                    var nVO = {
                        ErrorMessage: bnadd_msg_005
                    }
                    TeaLeaf.Event.tlAddCustomEvent(subtype, nVO);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                if (f.email2 && (f.email2.value != f.email1.value) && (!editEmail(f.email1.value, 'Email Address'))) {
                    return false;
                } else return true;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Here's my form:

```
<form action="/formmail/formmail.php" onsubmit="return validatecompare()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="ContactForm" id="ContactForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="env_report" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT,AUTH_TYPE,REMOTE_USER" />

    <!-- STEP 2: Put your email address in the 'recipients' value.
                 Note that you also have to allow this email address in the
                 $TARGET_EMAIL setting within formmail.php!
    -->
    <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value="sales_*_comtechnorthamerica.com" />

    <!-- STEP 3: Specify required fields in the 'required' value - or leave unchanged.
            NOTE: DO NOT put your email address and name here.
            "Your email address" and "Your name" are error messages for your users to see,
            not placeholders for you to replace.
    -->
    <input type="hidden" name="required" value="FullName:-Your name,Title:-Your title,Company:-Your company,Website:-Your website,Address:-Your address,Telephone:-Your telephone,email1:-Your email address,email2:-Your Confirm email address" />

    <!-- STEP 4: Put your subject line in the 'subject' value. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Comtech Contact Form Submission Testing" />

    <!-- ALL DONE! Visit our site for HOW TO guides and more complex features. -->

    <!-- this derives (creates) "email" and "realname" special fields from the input fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="derive_fields" value="email=email,realname=FullName" />

    <!-- this excludes the "email" and "realname" special fields from the body of the email you receive -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="mail_options" value="Exclude=email;realname" /> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="good_url" value="http://www.comtechnorthamerica.com/thankYou.php" />
         <table width="380" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" class="layoutFormBox"><h1>Information Request Form</h1>
                <table width="360" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Send_product_literature" id="Send_product_literature" value="Yes" />
                    </div></td>
                    <td><div align="left"> Send product literature</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Have_a_salesperson_contact_me" id="Have_a_salesperson_contact_me" value="Yes" />
                    </div></td>
                    <td><div align="left"> Have a salesperson contact me</div></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>                
                <br />
                <table width="360" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="335" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top"><div class="required" align="left">* denotes required field</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="70" valign="top"><div align="right">Name:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td width="335" valign="top"><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="FullName" id="FullName" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Title:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Company:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Website:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="Website" id="Website" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Address:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <textarea name="Address" rows="4" id="Address"></textarea>
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Telephone:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="Telephone" id="Telephone" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Cell Phone:</div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="Cell" id="Cell" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Fax:</div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="Fax" id="Fax" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Email:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Confirm Email:<span class="required">*</span></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" />
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Primary Interest:</div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <select name="Primary_Interest" id="Primary_Interest">
                        <option>In-line spring coiling, testing, spring detangling systems</option>
                        <option>Laser marking systems</option>
                        <option>Feeder bowl technology</option>
                        <option>Drum technology for spring &amp; parts handling / feeding</option>
                          </select>
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right">Comments:</div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <textarea name="Comments" rows="6" id="Comments"></textarea>
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><div align="left">How did you hear about Comtech?</div></td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="right"></div></td>
                    <td valign="top"><div align="left">
                      <select name="How_did_you_hear_about_Comtech" id="How_did_you_hear_about_Comtech">
                        <option>Google Search</option>
                        <option>Direct Mailing</option>
                        <option>Thomas Register</option>
                        <option>Trade Magazine</option>
                        <option>Tradeshow</option>
                        <option>Comtech Literature</option>
                        <option>Sales Representative</option>
                        <option>Customer Referral</option>
                        <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
                      </select>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="37" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top"><input type="submit" onclick="validatecompare()" value="Submit" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please read some [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking any questions. It will help us to answer your question more precisely!! :)